# Javascript switch statement does not work

Tags: javascript, html

This code works perfectly. But if I uncomment the switch statement, it fails completely. The switch statement seems to be correct. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
function draw(n) {

  let canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
  let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.fillStyle = 'black'

  let contourInterval = 1500
  let contourWidth = 500
  let fsize = 1000
  let x0 = fsize / 2
  let y0 = fsize / 2

  for (j = 0, y = -y0; j < fsize; j++, y++) {
    for (i = 0, x = -x0; i < fsize; i++, x++) {
      /*    
        switch(n) {
          case 0:
            let fun = (x*x + y*y)
            break;
          case 1:
            let fun = (x*x - y*y)                       
            break;
          case 2:
            let fun = 1.0/(x*x + y*y)
            break;
          default:
            let fun = (x*x + y*y)
        }
      */

      let fun = (x * x + y * y)
      if (Math.abs(fun % contourInterval) < contourWidth) {
        context.fillRect(x + x0 / 2, y + y0 / 2, 1, 1)
      }
    }
  }
}

draw(1)
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could you also explain what you mean by "it fails completely"? Did you get unexpected behavior? Was there an error message?

Comment: Probably `let fun` in `switch` makes `fun` available only in `switch`. Try to declare it first: `let fun; switch(n){...}`

Comment: "let" is not "assign a new value", but "declare a new variable in a *local* scope"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're declaring the `fun` variable inside the `switch` statement and then trying to use it outside later.

Try updating your code to the following:

```js
function draw(n) {

  let canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
  let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.fillStyle = 'black'

  let contourInterval = 1500
  let contourWidth = 500
  let fsize = 1000
  let x0 = fsize / 2
  let y0 = fsize / 2

  for (j = 0, y = -y0; j < fsize; j++, y++) {
    for (i = 0, x = -x0; i < fsize; i++, x++) {
      let fun = 0 // declare this here outside the scope of the switch statement

      switch(n) {
        case 0:
          // remember to get rid of the `let` keywords in your `case` statments
          fun = (x*x + y*y)
          break;
        case 1:
          fun = (x*x - y*y)                       
          break;
        case 2:
          fun = 1.0/(x*x + y*y)
          break;
        default:
          fun = (x*x + y*y)
      }

      // now `fun` can be used here without scope problems
      if (Math.abs(fun % contourInterval) < contourWidth) {
        context.fillRect(x + x0 / 2, y + y0 / 2, 1, 1)
      }
    }
  }
}

draw(1)
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

This way you declare the variable in the outer scope and use the switch statement to set it. Now it can be used in the outer scope.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but I tried it just now and it makes no difference, it still fails.

Comment: Same error message? Please be specific with what you mean by "fails"

Comment: In fact, adding let fun = 0 just above the switch, makes it fail even with the switch commented out. Very strange...

Comment: By fails, I mean nothing is drawn in the canvas. Nothing happens at all.

Comment: Yeah of course it would if you've got the switch statement commented out because then the value wouldn't change and you'd have your linter complaining about a `let` that isn't being changed.

Comment: There's no "error message."

Comment: Adding let fun = 0 makes it fail period. Even with the switch statement active. Are you running the code?

Comment: The code as originally posted works perfectly, with the switch commented out. Then it doesn't matter whether it's called with draw(0) or draw(1) since the parameter n is never used.

Comment: With the switch commented out, n is never used, as I said. So it makes no difference how draw is called. It will always behave the same.

Comment: Yes, it does matter with the switch statement active, but then nothing is drawn at all, that's why I posted this. When the switch is uncommented, nothing is drawn no matter how draw is called.

Comment: As I've said twice now, the code works perfectly as I originally posted it, with the switch commented out and fun set manually  to x^2 + y^2. Have you run the code I originally posted?

Comment: I did add the let fun = 0 statement as you suggested and that made the whole thing fail, no output at all.

Comment: Yes, let fun = x^2 + y^2 actually works! That's exactly what I posted in the first place. If that didn't work, I wouldn't have asked this question ar all.

Comment: Have you used the Run Code Snippet button? It will show you that the original code works.

Comment: Yep, and if you use the Run Code Snippet button in this answer you will see that my answer works too...

Answer (score 0):

Declare fun first

```js
function draw(n) {

  let canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
  let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.fillStyle = 'black'

  let contourInterval = 1500
  let contourWidth = 500
  let fsize = 1000
  let x0 = fsize / 2
  let y0 = fsize / 2

  for (j = 0, y = -y0; j < fsize; j++, y++) {
    for (i = 0, x = -x0; i < fsize; i++, x++) {
        let fun = 0
        
        switch(n) {
          case 0:
            fun = (x*x + y*y)
            break;
          case 1:
            fun = (x*x - y*y)                       
            break;
          case 2:
            fun = 1.0/(x*x + y*y)
            break;
          default:
            fun = (x*x + y*y)
        }
      if (Math.abs(fun % contourInterval) < contourWidth) {
        context.fillRect(x + x0 / 2, y + y0 / 2, 1, 1)
      }
    }
  }
}

draw(1)
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: I've copied that code and I'll try it on my system. I thought I had already copied it correctly, but maybe not...

Comment: Ok, it now works! Thanks a million and I'm sorry I caused confusion. Mea Culpa Maxima!

Comment: I figured out what was going wrong. I was making changes to the code in BBEdit, then doing a "save." But the file was not saved properly. When I do "save as," it works properly. Again, sorry for my confusion.